# ElasticSearch index schema getting modifed post addition of content

Tags: elasticsearch

I created a schema and then adding content. As soon as I add the content, the schema gets duplicated. I also have kibana running on top for searching. I am not able to figure out why this is happening. The data in Kibana is showing properly, but I am worried that this may cause some issues in the future. Please help.

My schema

```
{
    "properties": {
        "ansible_fqdn": { "type": "string" },
        "ansible_hostname": { "type": "string" },
        "ansible_architecture": { "type": "string" },
        "ansible_distribution": { "type": "string" },
        "ansible_distribution_version": { "type": "string" },
        "ansible_os_family": { "type": "string" },
        "facter_ipaddress": { "type": "string" },
        "facter_kernelrelease": { "type": "string" },
        "facter_memorysize": { "type": "string" },
        "facter_physicalprocessorcount": { "type": "integer" },
        "facter_timezone": { "type": "string" },
        "facter_virtual": { "type": "string" },
        "primary_service_name": { "type": "string" },
        "pp_name": { "type": "string" },
        "wg_project_name": { "type": "string" },
        "primary_app_name": { "type": "string" },
        "location": { "type": "string" },
        "status": { "type": "string" },
        "pp_idx": { "type": "string" }
    }
}
```

Schema post adding content

```
{
  "systeminformation" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "ansible_facts" : {
        "properties" : {
          "ansible_architecture" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "ansible_distribution" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "ansible_distribution_version" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "ansible_facts" : {
            "properties" : {
              "ansible_architecture" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "ansible_distribution" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "ansible_distribution_version" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "ansible_fqdn" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "ansible_hostname" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "ansible_os_family" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "facter_ipaddress" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "facter_kernelrelease" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "facter_memorysize" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "facter_physicalprocessorcount" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "facter_timezone" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "facter_virtual" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "status" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "location" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "pp_id" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "pp_name" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "primary_app_name" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "primary_service_name" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "wg_project_name" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "ansible_fqdn" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "ansible_hostname" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "ansible_os_family" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "facter_ipaddress" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "facter_kernelrelease" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "facter_memorysize" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "facter_physicalprocessorcount" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "facter_timezone" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "facter_virtual" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "status" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "location" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "pp_idx" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "pp_name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "primary_app_name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "primary_service_name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "wg_project_name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1470748490174",
        "uuid" : "r9Een_BXSf2cR3Cl2kb2Jg",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "2030499"
        }
      }
    },
    "warmers" : { }
  }
}
```

Content that is being added

```
{"ansible_facts": {"ansible_fqdn": "hostname.domain.com", "ansible_hostname": "hostname", "ansible_architecture": "x86_64", "ansible_distribution": "OracleLinux", "ansible_distribution_version": "6", "ansible_os_family": "RedHat", "facter_ipaddress": "10.10.10.10", "facter_kernelrelease": "2.6", "facter_memorysize": "16 GB", "facter_physicalprocessorcount": 2, "facter_timezone": "UTC", "facter_virtual": "vmware", "primary_service_name": "Something", "pp_name": "abc", "wg_project_name": "something", "primary_app_name": "something", "location": "", "status": "use", "pp_id": "P"}}
```

Comment: Could it happen that you accidentally sent different objects to Elasticsearch? If you delete your current index, and then send data again, do you observe the same behavior?

Comment: What's the complete indexing command that you use?

Comment: To me it looks like you did `POST /my_index/ansible_facts/12345 {"ansible_facts": {"ansible_fqdn":....}}` while you should have done it like `POST /my_index/ansible_facts/12345 {"ansible_fqdn":....}`

Comment: @oldbam, I deleted the complete index and added it multiple times and everytime the same result.

AndreiStefan, these are the command I am using:
Create Index
curl -X PUT "testserver:9200/systeminformation?pretty"
Add mapping
curl -X PUT "testserver:9200/systeminformation/ansible_facts/_mapping?pretty" --data-binary @ schema.json
Add content
curl -X POST "testserver:9200/systeminformation/ansible_facts?pretty" -d @ testsystem.json
curl -X POST "testserver:9200/systeminformation/ansible_facts?pretty" -d @ testsystem2.json

Comment: can you show code/web request how you add data to your index?

Comment: @AndreiStefan, your advice helped. I removed the ansible_facts part and the schema is not getting duplicated. Thanks. Can you explain why this may be happening. And can a comment be marked as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like you did `POST /my_index/ansible_facts/12345 {"ansible_facts": {"ansible_fqdn":....}}` while you should have done it like `POST /my_index/ansible_facts/12345 {"ansible_fqdn":....}`.

The type name (`ansible_facts`) is in both the URL of the command and, also, in the body of the command. And [*the mapping itself is very flexible and is schema-free*](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-index_.html#index-creation) which means that, if otherwise not specifically mentioned in your own mapping, Elasticsearch will create fields for new data in the document. And your mistake from the command created a new field - `ansible_facts` - with sub-fields in it. So, technically, the mapping is not duplicated (this is not possible with ES), it has a new field added to it, a field with many sub-fields.